# Is it possible to inject angular 2 router in directive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to inject angular 2 router in a directive which extends the RouterOutlet I use this instead of the traditional outlet to have a authentication flow

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class APPLICATION_ROUTER_DIRECTIVE extends RouterOutlet {
    constructor(parentOutletMap:RouterOutletMap, location:ViewContainerRef, componentFactoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver, name:string) {
        super(parentOutletMap, location, componentFactoryResolver, name);
    }

    activate(activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute, providers, outletMap) {
        let requiredUserRoles = activatedRoute.snapshot['_routeConfig'] ? activatedRoute.snapshot['_routeConfig'].roles : null;
        if (this.authorizeRoute(requiredUserRoles)) {
            return super.activate(activatedRoute, providers, outletMap);
        }
        else {
            let activeUserRole = AuthorizationService.getUserRole();
            switch (activeUserRole) {
                case null:
                case Role.ANONYMUS:
                case Role.USER: {
                    window.location.href = '/#';
                    break;
                }
                case Role.ADMIN: {
                    window.location.href = '/#/admin/users';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    authorizeRoute(requiredRoles:Array<string>):boolean {
        let authorized = false;
        let activeUserRole = AuthorizationService.getUserRole();

        if (!requiredRoles) {
            requiredRoles = [Role.ANONYMUS, Role.USER];
        }

        if (!activeUserRole) {
            activeUserRole = Role.ANONYMUS;
        }

        return requiredRoles.indexOf(activeUserRole) !== -1;
    }

}
```

If I inject the router is undefined, I want from switch case to navigate to the proper pages which are the default for users/admins

Comment: Is it possible to inject the router or should I just use the refrash of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You want routing that uses authentication.  No injections and directive components don't really care (or know) about routing.

Look at the section called "Route Guards" and the CanActivate feature
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

**BUT but the bigger question is**, "Can you authorize in client side JS?"  No, not really.  You might have to think about how to move your authorization server side to make it truly secure.

Comment: I agree I will change it to a server check, but I wanted to move all what is authentication to the router, so I can catch the activation and redirect from there to not write can activate all over again, something more like a filter